# Convert IHtmlContent/TagBuilder to string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5. I need to convert IHtmlContent to String

`IIHtmlContent` is part of the `ASP.NET 5` `Microsoft.AspNet.Html.Abstractions` namespace and is an interface that `TagBuilder` implements

Simplified I have the following method

```
public static IHtmlContent GetContent()
{
    return new HtmlString("<tag>blah</tag>");
}
```

When I reference it

```
string output = GetContent().ToString();
```

I get the following output for GetContent()

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder"
```

and not

```
<tag>blah</tag>
```

which I want

I also tried using StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
html.Append(GetContent());
```

but it also appends the same namespace and not the string value

I tried to cast it to TagBuilder

```
TagBuilder content = (TagBuilder)GetContent();
```

but TagBuilder doesn't have a method that converts to string

How do I convert IHtmlContent or TagBuilder to a string?

Comment: What about `ToHtmlString`? Also, where do you get `IHtmlContent` from?

Comment: I was referring to `HtmlString` class's method. Can you point me to the documentation for `IHtmlContent`? It doesn't seem to be on MSDN

Comment: It's seven years ago, but maybe it's usefull for someone anymore. If you call GetContent() from your html source code file (e.g.: in your cshtml: @Model.GetContent()) then in your browser app you'll see: blah. Therefor contains the question also a piece of an answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If all you need to do is output the contents as a string, just add this method and pass your IHtmlContent object as a parameter to get the string output:

```
public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {        
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Good answer.. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Does not work on asp.vnext core. use `HtmlEncoder.Default` instead

Comment: Shouldn't the `StringWriter` be wrapped in a `using` block?

Comment: @bradlis7 you are correct. I have updated the solution to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: With Razor in Core you can simply use `@tagBuilderInstance`. It will build and write the result.

Comment: @androbin with classic ASPNET too, but the question was to output the HTML content from the partial to a string variable, to manipulate it as pleased.

Answer (score 28):

Adding to the answer above:

The new instance of the `HtmlEncoder` doesn't work in  ASP.NET Core RTM as the `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders` namespace was  removed and the new `HtmlEncoder` class is moved to a new namespace `System.Text.Encodings.Web`, but this class is now written as an abstract and sealed class so you can't create a new instance or a derived class from it.

Pass `HtmlEncoder.Default` to the method and it will work

```
public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
{
    var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

ASP.NET Core actually introduced handful of careful optimizations. If you are building an HTML extension method, then the most efficient way is to avoid string:

```
public static IHtmlContent GetContent(this IHtmlHelper helper)
{
    var content = new HtmlContentBuilder()
                     .AppendHtml("<ol class='content-body'><li>")
                     .AppendHtml(helper.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"))
                     .AppendHtml("</li>");

    if(SomeCondition())
    {
        content.AppendHtml(@"<div>
            Note `HtmlContentBuilder.AppendHtml()` is Mutable
            as well as Fluent/Chainable.
        </div>");
    }

    return content;
}
```

<del>Finally in the razor view, we don't even need `@Html.Raw(Html.GetContent())` anymore (which used to be required in ASP.NET MVC 5)</del> *- not valid based on Lukáš Kmoch comment below: `ASP.NET MVC 5 has type MvcHtmlString. You don't need to use Html.Raw()`*

just calling `@Html.GetContent()` is sufficient and Razor will take care of all the escaping business.

Comment: The reason I liked the server side rendering is that it was so much faster to code boring markup at the expense of performance.  Why are we injecting an ordered list into markup so we can render and anchor tag? This has to be bad for SEO, and increase development time.  Arrrgh

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 has type MvcHtmlString. You don't need to use Html.Raw()

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method so you can use it like ToString().

```
    public static string ToHtmlString(this IHtmlContent content)
    {
        if (content is HtmlString htmlString)
        {
            return htmlString.Value;
        }

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Views.TestCommon/HtmlContentUtilities.cs

```
public static string HtmlContentToString(IHtmlContent content, HtmlEncoder encoder = null)
        {
            if (encoder == null)
            {
                encoder = new HtmlTestEncoder();
            }

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                content.WriteTo(writer, encoder);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```