# asp.net core 1.0 mvc RC2 tagBuilder method with HtmlEncoder() worked in RC1 not working RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In RC1 I had the following small method that worked.

```
    public string ConvertTagToSring(TagBuilder Tag)
    {
        var writer = new StringWriter();

        Tag.WriteTo(writer, new HtmlEncoder());

        return writer.ToString();
    }
```

As the method shows its to convert a Tagbuilder tag into a string using a stringWriter().

I am getting an error on "new HtmlEncoder()" and the error is:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'HtmlEncoder'

I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/101) on HtmlEncoder in the breaking changes section of Asp.Net/Announcements however I cant figure out how to change it to work..

How can I refactor:

```
Tag.WriteTo(writer, new HtmlEncoder());
```

so that I can convert the tag to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HtmlEncoder` is now an abstract class and can't be initialized ([see HttpEncoder.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs#L16) on the [dotnet\corefx GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/)).

It has a default implementation (`DefaultHtmlEncoder`), which is internal. But `HtmlEncoder` exposes a static property `Default` that has a reference to the default implementation of it, [see HttpEncoder.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs#L21-L24).

So instead of calling `new HtmlEncoder()` you just call `HtmlEncoder.Default`. I guess it's an optimization attempt to avoid having the `HtmlEncoder` being initialized multiple times per request.

Comment: Whilst I believe this is the correct answer I am having some trouble implementing it. Is it possible to give an example using my simple method above?  I, incidentally got my original answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667308/convert-ihtmlcontent-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c-sharp) and in particular @Phasiq 's answer.

Comment: Sorry it was late night and had a type. `HtmlEncoder.Default` is what you call. i.e. `Tag.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);` which uses the default implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Use dependency injection to obtain active (configured) `HtmlEncoder` instance.

Encoder can be configured  (in `Startup`) to not encode some unicode characters (Cyrillic, etc), while `DefaultHtmlEncoder.Singleton` [encodes everything  except `UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs#L51).

Comment: You can pass the configuration only via constructor and `DefaultHtmlEncoder` is marked internal sealed. Which other class implements `HttpEncoder` abstract class? Yesterday I only found the Unit test related classes

Comment: Yes, `DefaultHtmlEncoder` is `internal sealed`, but not `HtmlEncoder` itself - you can replace default one with own implementation via DI in `Startup.cs`. Moreover, [`public static HtmlEncoder.Create`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs#L31) allows you to create new `DefaultHtmlEncoder` instance with custom `TextEncoderSettings`