# Rendering PartialView in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am rendering a Partialview as HTML string into a popover and I want to get an advice from you guys to ensure if my approach is correct

I have the following simple code

```
<button class="btn-link" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-content="@Html.Partial("_Reminder").ToHtmlString()"><span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Unsecured</span></button>
```

The partial view I am rendering is the following

```
    Reminder me : 
 <button class="btn btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-time" title="Tomorrow"></button> 
    <button class="btn btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" title="In 1 Week"></button>  
    <button class="btn btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-check" title="In 1 Month"></button>
```

Result is pretty impressive but i am not sure if this is the right way to do that where i don't want a MODEL Popup and also i want to render this partial view right at the top of each item when clicked

Results are the following

[image]

But is there a better way to deal with this?

Also, I will have to Pass an ITEM ID to the partial view, therefore, i was thinking to use `@{Html.RenderAction("ViewReminder", "Home", new { ID = 1 }); }` instead of `@Html.Partial("_Reminder").ToHtmlString()`

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer: [Convert IHtmlContent/TagBuilder to string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667308/convert-ihtmlcontent-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c-sharp#)

I implemented the Helper:

```
public static class HtmlContentExtension
{
    public static string GetString(this IHtmlContent content)
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

And I used it in View:

```
string meta = Html.Partial("Meta", Model.Meta).GetString();
<span class="pop" title="Meta" data-html="true" data-content="@meta">@Model.Points</span>
```

PS:
I used "HtmlEncoder.Default" because I'm using Core, if I use the ASP MVC default, use "new HtmlEncoder()".