# Asp.Net Core 2.1.0-preview1-final: @Html.ActionLink() is not working for string.Format()

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

```
<div data-collapse class="left-justify" id="requirements">
  @Html.Raw(string.Format(@_stringLocalizer["RegisterNoticeMessage"], @Html.ActionLink(@_stringLocalizer["RegisterLinkDisplayName"], "Register")))
</div>
```

In this piece of code, **@Html.ActionLink()** is returning **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder** instead of returning anchor element containing URL path to the specified action.
What is the right way to use **@Html.ActionLink()** in **string.Format()**. Or, do I missing anything, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper method `Html.ActionLink` always returns a `TagBuilder` object. When you pass such an object into a `string` parameter, the `ToString()` method will be called, resulting in your observed output (the class name: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder").

It seems to me you are trying to create a hyperlink in a rather weird way. Have you tried using the `Url.Action` helper method? This method returns a plain old `string`, ready to plug into any href attribute.

E.g. this code would be equivalent of what you're trying to achieve:

```
@Html.Raw(
    string.Format(_stringLocalizer["RegisterNoticeMessage"], 
    "<a href=\"" + Url.Action("Register") + "\">" + _stringLocalizer["RegisterLinkDisplayName"] + "</a>")
)
```

Sidenotes:

- It **is** possible get the `string` value of a TagBuilder, as illustrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667308/convert-ihtmlcontent-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c-sharp) post.
- No need to repeat `@` when you're already working in Razor/C# context.
- Be extremely careful when using `Html.Raw` as it might result in XSS vulnerabilities.