# Net Core: Convert String to TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The following code converts a `TagBuilder` to a `String`.
What is the opposite? How do I convert reverse, a `String` to a `TagBuilder`?
Looking for a solution.

[Convert IHtmlContent/TagBuilder to string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667308/convert-ihtmlcontent-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c-sharp)

```
public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {        
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: TagBuilder implements the IHtmlContent interface, does it offer any methods to take a string input and TagBuilder output? Isn't a TagBuilder just a collection of html elements?

Comment: not sure,trying to research

Comment: If by convert a string to tagbuilder you mean taking the entire html string and creating an instance of Tagbuilder, then you can't. However you can pass the tag name as an argument if you want. I believe [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#parameters) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @JeremyWatkins https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Doing research should be done _before_ taking the step to ask on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 7):

As an option you can use an html parser like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and get a html node, then create a [`TagBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) using node's name, attributes and inner html:

```
public TagBuilder GetTagBuilder(string html)
{
    var node = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode(html);
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(node.Name);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(node.Attributes.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value));
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml = node.InnerHtml;
    return tagBuilder;
}
```

For example:

```
var html = @"<div id=""div1"" class=""class1"">Something</div>";
var tagBuilder = GetTagBuilder(html);
var str = tagBuilder.ToString();
```

Then the `str` value would be:

```
<div class="class1" id="div1">Something</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**with XmlDocument**

```
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(html);
TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(doc.DocumentElement.Name);
tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Cast<System.Xml.XmlAttribute>().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value));
tagBuilder.InnerHtml = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
return tagBuilder;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by first generating an XElement node from the string thusly:

```
public static XElement? ToElement(this IHtmlContent content)
        {
            using StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
            content.WriteTo(sw, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            string html = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

            string wrapper = $"<div>{html}</div>";
            var root = XElement.Parse(wrapper);
            XElement? element = root.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
            return element;
        }
```

Once I have the string in as an XElement I can convert it to a TagBuilder thusly:

```
public static TagBuilder ToTagbuilder(this IHtmlContent content)
        {
            var element = content.ToElement() ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(content));

            TagBuilder builder = new(element.Name.LocalName);
            foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
            {
                var name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                var value = attribute.Value;
                builder.Attributes[name] = value;
            }
            return builder;

        }
```

Kindly note that this will work so long as the string is a single element. Some sort of recursion would have to implemented to inspect for child or sibling elements.