# Net Core: How to Convert TagBuilder to String in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tagbuilder

Is there a native way to convert  Tagbuilder to String in Net Core? This only is for ASP Net 5. [Convert IHtmlContent/TagBuilder to string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667308/convert-ihtmlcontent-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c-sharp)

Convert value of TagBuilder into a String

I think Microsoft had a replacement function for this in Net Core

```
public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {        
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The same `WriteTo` method is available in [aspnetcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.ihtmlcontent.writeto?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

You should be able to continue to benefit from creating the same GetString method, as `TagBuilder` inherits from `IHtmlContent`.

#### For example:

```cs
public static class IHtmlContentExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent content)
    {
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {        
            content.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then from your code, you can just call

```cs
TagBuilder myTag = // ...
string tagAsText = myTag.GetString();
```

Comment: I asked if there is another method, I already listed this above, does C# have a Native function?

Comment: Good answer but I had to jump in here, don't call the class IHtmlContentExtensions, 'I' prefix is normally reserved for interfaces.

Comment: That's a fair point. I named it that because its extending an interface called IHtmlContent, but you're right about the I prefix usually being reserved for interfaces

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me!

```
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            result.Append(GetString(tag));
        }

        return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
```