# TagBuilder AddCssClass Order, Adds to Beginning, how to Add New Class at the End?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, tagbuilder

I noticed Tagbuilder AddCssClass adds tags to the Beginning. How do I make it add it to the end.

```
TagBuilder test = new TagBuilder("div");
toolset.AddCssClass("Number1");
toolset.AddCssClass("Number2");
```

In this situation, Number2 will be first.

Comment: Why do you care about ordering css class names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Mvc/TagBuilder.cs#L54-L66), it doesn't seem like it's possible to add the class onto the end using the method that you are. The code for AddCssClass looks like this:

```
public void AddCssClass(string value)
{
    string currentValue;

    if (Attributes.TryGetValue("class", out currentValue))
    {
        Attributes["class"] = value + " " + currentValue;
    }
    else
    {
        Attributes["class"] = value;
    }
}
```

Fortunately for us, the TagBuilder object exposes `Attributes`, so we can write an extension method which adds the value to the end rather than the beginning:

```
public static class TagBuilderExtensions
{
    public void AddCssClassEnd(this TagBuilder tagBuilder, string value)
    {
        string currentValue;

        if (tagBuilder.Attributes.TryGetValue("class", out currentValue))
        {
            tagBuilder.Attributes["class"] = currentValue + " " + value;
        }
        else
        {
            tagBuilder.Attributes["class"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And provided you have a `using` for the namespace you define the above extension method in, you can simply use it like so:

```
toolset.AddCssClassEnd("Number1");
```

Comment: See the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Mvc/TagBuilder.cs#L54-L66) I provided. The code for most .NET libraries are made available on GitHub by Microsoft.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend when using this code adding *a long comment* explaining why this is important for your particular case - since order of class names does not matter for CSS most people will assume that order does not matter and get confused by the effort. Good comment inline and possibly unit tests with good reasoning may help.

Comment: ok, I was just reading here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css

Comment: hi @John you may know answer to this one also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119863/add-css-class-to-all-tags-in-tagbuilder   or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025984/net-core-how-to-convert-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c