# TagHelperOutput Add Attribute to End, Not Beginning

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I noticed TagHelperOutput Attribute.Add, adds text to Beginning for each attribute. How do I make it add it to end for each attribute.

```
base.Process(context, output);
output.Attributes.Add("class","test");
```

So currently if the existing class is "button", new class will be "test button". I want it to be "button test" for all classes in html tree

This question is for TagBuilder ,

[TagBuilder AddCssClass Order, Adds to Beginning, how to Add New Class at the End?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105604/tagbuilder-addcssclass-order-adds-to-beginning-how-to-add-new-class-at-the-end)

Comment: How doesn't the question you link to answer your question?

Comment: attributes["class"]  was giving error.  taghelper output is different than tagbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize a `CreateOrMergeAttribute` method in your tag helper and add new css class to the attribute list first. like below :

```
    public class EmailTagHelper: TagHelper
{
    private const string EmailDomain = "contoso.com";

    // Can be passed via <email mail-to="..." />. 
    // PascalCase gets translated into kebab-case.
    public string MailTo { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag

        var address = MailTo + "@" + EmailDomain;

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + address);
        output.Content.SetContent(address);

        CreateOrMergeAttribute("class", "test", output);
    }

    private void CreateOrMergeAttribute(string name, object content, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var currentAttribute = output.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(attribute => attribute.Name == name);
        if (currentAttribute == null)
        {
            var attribute = new TagHelperAttribute(name, content);
            output.Attributes.Add(attribute);
        }
        else
        {
            var newAttribute = new TagHelperAttribute(
                name,
                $"{currentAttribute.Value.ToString()} {content.ToString()}",
                currentAttribute.ValueStyle);
            output.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
            output.Attributes.Add(newAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot of result :

[image]