# Html helper extension not rendering on page (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

In my ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application, I've created a `HtmlHelperExtensions` file so I can easily create a bootstrap carousel.

When trying to use this in my view, however, the only thing rendered to the page is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder` and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's the code for the Carousel extension:

```
public static IHtmlContent Carousel(this IHtmlHelper html, IList<string> imageSources)
{
    var carouselWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    carouselWrapper.AddCssClass("carousel slide");
    carouselWrapper.MergeAttribute("data-ride", "carousel");
    
    var innerDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
    innerDiv.AddCssClass("carousel-inner");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSources.Count; i++)
    {
        var itemDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        itemDiv.AddCssClass("carousel-item");
    
        if (i == 0)
        {
            itemDiv.AddCssClass("active");
        }
    
        var image = new TagBuilder("img");
        image.MergeAttribute("src", imageSources[i]);
        image.AddCssClass("d-block w-100");
        image.MergeAttribute("alt", "Image " + (i + 1));
    
        itemDiv.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(image);
        innerDiv.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(itemDiv);
    }
    
    carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(innerDiv);

    var prevButton = CreateControlButton("carousel-control-prev", "prev", "Previous");
    var nextButton = CreateControlButton("carousel-control-next", "next", "Next");

    carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(prevButton);
    carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(nextButton);

    return new HtmlString(carouselWrapper.ToString());
}

private static TagBuilder CreateControlButton(string className, string slideDirection, string ariaLabel)
{
    var button = new TagBuilder("button");
    button.AddCssClass(className);
    button.MergeAttribute("type", "button");
    button.MergeAttribute("data-target", "#carouselExampleAutoplaying");
    button.MergeAttribute("data-slide", slideDirection);

    var iconSpan = new TagBuilder("span");
    iconSpan.AddCssClass("carousel-control-" + slideDirection + "-icon");
    iconSpan.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

    var visuallyHiddenSpan = new TagBuilder("span");
    visuallyHiddenSpan.AddCssClass("visually-hidden");
    visuallyHiddenSpan.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(ariaLabel);

    button.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(iconSpan);
    button.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(visuallyHiddenSpan);

    return button;
}
```

After creating this, I then added the html extension to my _ViewImports file as:

```
@using ThatDaleDudes_Plugins.Infrastructure.Extensions
```

Finally, I used the extension on a view by doing:

```
@Html.Carousel(Model.TestSources.ToList())
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

I've tried changing the code in the view to be the following with no luck:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Carousel(Model.TestSources.ToList()))
```

I've also tried changing the type returned by the `Carousel` extension method from `HtmlString` to `IHtmlContent` but nothing seemed to change.

Comment: Don't call `ToString()` on `TagBuilder`, Use it's `WriteTo` method and write it to a `TextWriter` and call the `ToString` method of `TextWriter`. [microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder.writeto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder.writeto?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and relevant SO post: [net-core-how-to-convert-tagbuilder-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025984/net-core-how-to-convert-tagbuilder-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IHtmlContent Carousel(this IHtmlHelper html, IList<string> imageSources)
{
    var carouselWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
    // your existing code

    // Instead of using ToString(), use a StringWriter
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        carouselWrapper.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Use `StringWriter` with `TagBuilder`. Replace `ToString()` with `WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default)` to properly generate HTML from TagBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out thanks to the comment by Ryan.

In the end, I created a new method for for converting the HtmlContent to a string and I then changed the return type of the Carousel method to HtmlString and returned a new HtmlString of the carousel content.

Carousel method was updated to:

```
public static HtmlString Carousel(this IHtmlHelper html, IList<string> imageSources)
    {
        var carouselWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
        carouselWrapper.AddCssClass("carousel slide");
        carouselWrapper.MergeAttribute("data-ride", "carousel");
        
        var innerDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        innerDiv.AddCssClass("carousel-inner");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < imageSources.Count; i++)
        {
            var itemDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
            itemDiv.AddCssClass("carousel-item");
        
            if (i == 0)
            {
                itemDiv.AddCssClass("active");
            }
        
            var image = new TagBuilder("img");
            image.MergeAttribute("src", imageSources[i]);
            image.AddCssClass("d-block w-100");
            image.MergeAttribute("alt", "Image " + (i + 1));
        
            itemDiv.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(image);
            innerDiv.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(itemDiv);
        }
        
        carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(innerDiv);

        var prevButton = CreateControlButton("carousel-control-prev", "prev", "Previous");
        var nextButton = CreateControlButton("carousel-control-next", "next", "Next");

        carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(prevButton);
        carouselWrapper.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(nextButton);

        return new HtmlString(carouselWrapper.GetString());
    }
```

And the new GetString extension method for HtmlContent I created was this:

```
private static string GetString(this IHtmlContent content)
    {
        using var writer = new StringWriter();
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
```